# lambda function as argument of lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I am stuck with some code in python where there are lambda functions as argument of the lambda functions. After wasting a lot of time on that code, I am trying understand this concept with a small code. I tried writing a small sample code which works fine.

```
def multiply(a,b):
    return a*b
def mathematical(X1, X2, X3):
    sum = X1 + X2 +X3
    return sum
multiplication = lambda x,y: multiply(x,y)
mathematical_function= lambda X1, X2: mathematical(X1, X2, multiplication(X1, X2))*2
result = mathematical_function(3,4)
print(result)
```

Then I tried putting the entire lambda function as argument as shown below but I am getting the ERROR. I am expecting to get the same result as for above code.

```
def multiply(a,b):
    return a*b
def mathematical(X1, X2, X3):
    sum = X1 + X2 +X3
    return sum
multiplication = lambda x,y: multiply(x,y)
mathematical_function= lambda X1, X2: mathematical(X1, X2, lambda x,y: multiply(x,y))*2 
result = mathematical_function(3,4)       # Problem
print(result)
```

### **The error I am getting is as below:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[73], line 1
----> 1 result = mathematical_function(3,4)       # Problem
      2 print(result)

Cell In[72], line 1, in (X1, X2)
----> 1 mathematical_function= lambda X1, X2: mathematical(X1, X2, lambda x,y: multiply(x,y))*2   # Some problem

Cell In[70], line 2, in mathematical(X1, X2, X3)
      1 def mathematical(X1, X2, X3):
----> 2     sum = X1 + X2 +X3
      3     return sum

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function
```

It would be great help if I can be helped in solving this problem since I am new to python and lambda function.

Comment: So what's the question? What's the intent of putting this in a lambda? What's the desired behaviour and what exactly isn't working as you expected it to?

Comment: Thank you @LieRyan for the response. I am trying to understand the concept of lambda function. I am completely stuck with the lines 300- 306 in this code https://github.com/thubregtsen/qhack/blob/master/paper/noiseless_checkerboard_and_donuts.py. So, I thought i should try writing a small code where a lambda function is passed as argument to lambda function but I am getting the ERROR.

Comment: @LieRyan I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiplication` is a reference to a function defined as `lambda x,y: multiply(x,y)`. You could substitute `lambda x,y: multiply(x,y)` for `multiplication` without changing your code's behavior. That's not what you did, though.

Instead of substituting `lambda x,y: multiply(x,y)` for `multiplication`, you substituted it for `multiplication(X1, X2)`. You took out the part where you call the function. You need to keep that part. The correct substitution would produce

```
(lambda x,y: multiply(x,y))(X1, X2)
```

not just

```
lambda x,y: multiply(x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you @user2357117 for the response. Your solution works. Is it possible that code works without putting (X1, X2) ?

Comment: @Manu no, I don't think you understand. `lambda x,y: multiply(x,y)` is a reference to the function, _not_ the result of CALLING the function. To call the function you need the additional `(lambda ... )(X1, X2)` notation

Answer (score 0):

@Manu the problem is you are trying to send lambda function(type =function) as a argument in this code `mathematical_function= lambda X1, X2: mathematical(X1, X2, lambda x,y: multiply(x,y))*2` and trying to receive it at

```
def mathematical(X1, X2, X3):
    sum = X1 + X2 +X3
    return sum
```

here x3 is expected to int as mentioned in the error log `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function`

Mycode:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

def mathematical(X1, X2, X3):
    total = X1 + X2 + X3
    return total

multiplication = lambda x, y: multiply(x, y)
mathematical_function = lambda X1, X2: mathematical(X1, X2, multiplication(X1, X2))
result = mathematical_function(3, 4)
print(result)
```

result:19

Comment: Thank you @Amith Anil George for the response.